# Check if an include (or require) exists

Tags: php, include, exists, require

How do you check if an include / require_once exists before you call it, I tried putting it in an error block, but PHP didn't like that.

I think `file_exists()` would work with some effort, however that would require the whole file path, and a relative include could not be passed into it easily.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: can you show us some code? can you basically explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GZipp: **To all of you who are suggesting the use of `file_exists()`:** *checks whether a file **or directory** exists*. `is_file()` would be a better fit in this case.

Comment: @Alix Axel: To all of you who are addressing me: I was suggesting nothing but that Smickie's assumption (that a relative path can't easily be transformed to a full path) was wrong. Others have pointed out that the full path isn't necessary; hence my comment rather than answer.

Comment: @Alix: `is_file()` *is* better than `file_exists()` but isn't it even better to use `is_readable()`?

Comment: @AgentConundrum: `is_readable()`: "Returns TRUE if the file **or directory** specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I believe `file_exists` does work with relative paths, though you could also try something along these lines...

`if(!@include("script.php")) throw new Exception("Failed to include 'script.php'");`

... needless to say, you may substitute the exception for any error handling method of your choosing. The idea here is that the `if`-statement verifies whether the file could be included, and any error messages normally outputted by `include` is supressed by prefixing it with `@`.

Comment: You don’t need the parentheses around the argument value of `include`. `include` is not a function but a language construct like `echo`.

Comment: @Gumbo I consider it good practice to use parantheses for language constructs, much like I do with `echo()` and `print()` as well.

Comment: I'm not sure is this a good solution: you will not see fatal errors.

Comment: @Michal Malunga: I'm not sure that you understand the question.

Comment: if you get an "cannot redeclare..." error when you remove the @-symbol in front of include try include_once instead.

Comment: @Johannes Gorset: Michał pointed out a very valid problem. I use the approach above (with mute operator) as well for a JSON RPC mechanism. And sometimes scripts fail without ANY error in the logfile. Linting your scripts makes sure that they do not fail due to a (muted) syntax error. However, some issues can only be detected at runtime, for example a class that tries to override a parent's public constructor with a private one. Very easy to fix and see *IF* you remember to remove the mute operator for debugging.

Comment: It better to use `include_once` or `require_once` , this will be helpful while using `OOP` Concept and avoiding redeclaring of classes again.

Comment: @Shi This is true, if someone uses this they'll have to be careful. I would mention though that in some situations it can be useful. My situation is that if a particular include_once does not occur, a class is missing so we need *more* action than the log file. If corrective measures dont work we send a message to the admin through their front-end user account. We also go ahead and throw a real error if a class is missing by require_once immediately after corrections.

Answer (score 12):

Check out the stream_resolve_include_path function,
it searches with the same rules as include().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php

Comment: A couple of user contributed notes here: stream_resolve_include_path() seems to cache it's output. After I renamed a file, I had to restart Apache for stream_resolve_include_path() to not return non-existing file name. This was on Windows.
It really behaves like `include` and will only resolve the filename against the include-path, if the path is relative. It makes not much sense to resolve already absolute pathnames anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You can also check for any variables, functions or classes defined in the include file and see if the include worked.

```
if (isset($variable)) { /*code*/ }
```

OR

```
if (function_exists('function_name')) { /*code*/ }
```

OR

```
if (class_exists('class_name')) { /*code*/ }
```

Comment: the problem here is that if the include will not work in the first place - it will throw and error / warning ..

Answer (score 7):

`file_exists()` works with relative paths, it'll also check if directories exist. Use `is_file()` instead:

```
if (is_file('./path/to/your/file.php'))
{
    require_once('./path/to/your/file.php');
}
```

Comment: While it works with relative paths, it does not work with include paths -- something to note ;)

Answer (score 6):

`file_exists` would work with checking if the required file exists when it is relative to the current working directory as it works fine with relative paths. However, if the include file was elsewhere on PATH, you would have to check several paths.

```
function include_exists ($fileName){
    if (realpath($fileName) == $fileName) {
        return is_file($fileName);
    }
    if ( is_file($fileName) ){
        return true;
    }

    $paths = explode(PS, get_include_path());
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $rp = substr($path, -1) == DS ? $path.$fileName : $path.DS.$fileName;
        if ( is_file($rp) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: file_exists can't search in the include paths. You would have to parse them manually.

Comment: PS == PATH_SEPARATOR && DS == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for those wondering,  +1, hoping you would fix it, this works great and without overhead of exception and error handlings

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way is to do:

```
if(file_exists(stream_resolve_include_path($filepath))){
  include $filepath;    
}
```

This is because [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) says that `stream_resolve_include_path` resolves the "filename against the include path according to the same rules as fopen()/include."

Some people suggested using `is_file` or `is_readable` but **that´s not for the general use case** because in the general use, if the file is blocked or unavailable for some reason after file_exists returns TRUE, that´s something you need to notice with a very ugly error message right on the final user´s face or otherwise you are open to unexpected and inexplicable behavior later with possible loss of data and things like that.